# How to represent table of contents in a table via LyX

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lyx

I am in need of urgent help regarding formatting the table of contents in Latex. In the thesis preparation guidelines provided by our university, the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables details should be enclosed within a table as shown below:

[image]

In this connection, my question is **How to generate the TOC, LOF, and LOT automatically in the above mentioned format using LyX.**

Comment: current [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) documentation has a section `22. The TOC as a table` which provides an example, together with the needed `etoc` style specifications. This should work for any document with only parts, sections, subsections. The `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` shoud be removed if you don't use package `hyperref`. I don't know `LyX` and I thus suspect that the raw `LaTeX ` code from this `etoc` documentation will prove discomcerting.

Comment: I have seen awkward requirements in the thesis guidelines, but so far, this is the  worst. Award for the most inelegant list of figures. `:)`.  BTW, in LyX, you need redefine the behaviour of `\listoffigures` LaTeX command in `Document` > `Settings` > `LaTeX Preamble` just as in plain LaTeX files (using `etoc` or something else) and then use `Insert` > `List/TOC`  > `List of Figures` in the main screen as usual in LyX.

Comment: @Fran I wasn't clear in my comment that `etoc` handles only tables of contents, not `list of figures` nor `list of tables`... sorry about that.